# Poor chap vs. poor woman

Tags: vocabulary

is there a similar expression for a woman who we want to express sympathy? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't there be? It can be *poor anything* - *poor man*, *poor boy*, *poor girl*, *lucky bloke*, *lucky lady*, *poor old girl*, *poor old boy* etc..

Comment: In the less politically correct era of the 1960s, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poor_Cow) is what might have passed.

Comment: Maybe *poor soul*.

Comment: Do you want the female equivalent of *chap*? As in: "Poor chap" refers to a man but "Poor ___" refers to a woman.

Comment: OK, I've opened the link and seen you've got the answer I would have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Try "poor lass". A quick Google search shows that it is a commonly accepted pair.

Comment: Or "poor lady".